# In Bootstrap 3, how can I turn a row of columns into a dropdown in mobile view?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a row of five graphics with text on them. In mobile view, I want to set up a media query so that the five graphics turn into a dropdown with text. For example, image 1 says "Personal Capability", image 2 says "Leading Change", etc. On mobile view, I want the graphics to go away and the dropdown to have options for "Personal Capability", "Leading Change", etc.

My HTML:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row" style="margin:1%">
  <div class="col-xs-1">
  </div>
  <!--end col-sm-1-->
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-responsive" title="Personal Capability" style="border:0">
    </a>
  </div>
  <!--end col-sm-2-->
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-responsive" title="Leading Change" style="border:0">
    </a>
  </div>
  <!--end col-sm-2-->
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-responsive" title="Character" style="border:0">
    </a>
  </div>
  <!--end col-sm-2-->
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-responsive" title="Interpersonal Skills" style="border:0">
    </a>
  </div>
  <!--end col-sm-2-->
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-responsive" title="Focus on Results" style="border:0">
    </a>
  </div>
  <!--end col-sm-2-->
  <div class="col-xs-1">
  </div>
  <!--end col-sm-1-->
</div>
<!--end row-->
```

Comment: That sort of complex transformation isn't practically feasible with a layout framework or CSS. You'll probably want to create duplicate structures and show/hide using breakpoint classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap provides Responsive utilities. There are some classes you can use to hide or show something according to the screen.

If I understand your problem, you want to display something on mobile only and other things on the other devices.

Bootstrap has something for you, the visible and hidden classes.

In this JSFiddle, you can find out a example of those classes : https://jsfiddle.net/valentinho14/9f4b53yw/

In addition, Please don't use empty block just to push content, like :

```
<div class="col-xs-1"></div>
```

It would be better if you choose to use the classes created for that(offset) :

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
    Your content
</div>
```

To have more informations about that, please check the official bootstrap's doc : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Thank you! I'm relatively new to bootstrap, so this is a huge help.

Comment: What is a best practice for aligning that dropdown in the center of the container?

Comment: There is several ways to center horizontally something in CSS.
But the easier way to do it, is to apply a custom class like with this : 
`margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this so you don't have to use duplicate content. It's simply using media queries to build a row of images/graphics above a certain breakpoint then hiding those images/graphics when the dropdown should appear.

The dropdown is just a standard  [button dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns). In the example a media query **@ min-width: 768px** is used to display the images and **@ max-width: 767px** to display the dropdown. You're simply changing the rules inside the `dropdown-menu` (which lends itself because it's just a list ultimately) to reflect the output you need, a row of images which you can extend if depending on how many images or reuse in other places with a different number of images.

**Basic CSS Change**

```
.btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
/*Default 6 Images but the % can be changed to accomodate or use/make a helper class*/
.btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu > li {
    display: inline-table;
    /*Adjust the below value based on the number of list items*/
    width: 16.666667%;
    float: none;
    /*Adjust the below value to add or remove space between list items*/
    padding: 2.5px;
}
```

**Example 1;** *Open at FullPage and reduce the browser window*

```css
/*Body rules are for DEMO ONLY*/

body {
  padding-top: 2.5px;
}
/*Body rules are for DEMO ONLY*/

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .btn-group-transform {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  /*Default 6 Images but the % can be changed to accomodate or use.make a helper class*/
  .btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu > li {
    display: inline-table;
    /*Adjust the below value based on the number of list items*/
    width: 16.666667%;
    float: none;
    /*Adjust the below value to add or remove space between list items*/
    padding: 2.5px;
  }
  /*If you want to extend this for a different number of images use these helpers or add new ones*/
  /*5 Images*/
  .btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu > li.list-5 {
    width: 20%;
  }
  /*4 Images*/
  .btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu > li.list-4 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  /*If you want to extend this for a different number of images use the above helpers or add new ones*/
  .btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    background: none;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu > li > a > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  .btn-group-transform button,
  .btn-group-transform span {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /*Body rules are for DEMO ONLY*/
  body {
    text-align: center;
  }
  /*Body rules are for DEMO ONLY*/
  .btn-group-transform img {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-transform">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-transform" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000/F21115/fff?text=ONE"> <span>Personal Capability</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000/F21115/fff?text=TWO"> <span>Leading Change</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000/F21115/fff?text=THREE"> <span>Character</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000/F21115/fff?text=FOUR"> <span>Interpersonal Skills</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000/F21115/fff?text=FIVE"> <span>Focus on Results</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000/F21115/fff?text=SIX"> <span>Something Else</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-transform">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-transform" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="list-5">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/000/fff?text=ONE"> <span>Personal Capability</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-5">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/000/fff?text=TWO"> <span>Leading Change</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-5">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/000/fff?text=THREE"> <span>Character</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-5">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/000/fff?text=FOUR"> <span>Interpersonal Skills</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-5">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/000/fff?text=FIVE"> <span>Focus on Results</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-transform">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-transform" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <li class="list-4">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/176B99/fff?text=ONE"> <span>Personal Capability</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-4">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/176B99/fff?text=TWO"> <span>Leading Change</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-4">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/176B99/fff?text=THREE"> <span>Character</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-4">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/176B99/fff?text=FOUR"> <span>Interpersonal Skills</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to actually use the text that will be displayed in the menu to overlay the image add this rule:

```
.btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu > li > a > span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

**Example 2:** *Open at FullPage and reduce the browser window*

```css
/*Body rules are for DEMO ONLY*/

body {
  padding-top: 2.5px;
}
/*Body rules are for DEMO ONLY*/

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .btn-group-transform {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu > li {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 20%;
    float: none;
    padding: 2.5px;
  }
  .btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    background: none;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  .btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu > li > a > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  /*Add this rule to use the text inside the dropdown to add a text overlay to the images*/
  .btn-group-transform .dropdown-menu > li > a > span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
  .btn-group-transform button {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /*Body rules are for DEMO ONLY*/
  body {
    text-align: center;
  }
  /*Body rules are for DEMO ONLY*/
  .btn-group-transform img {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-transform">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-transform" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/05A3F7/05A3F7"> <span>Personal Capability</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/05A3F7/05A3F7"> <span>Leading Change</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/05A3F7/05A3F7"> <span>Character</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/05A3F7/05A3F7"> <span>Interpersonal Skills</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600/05A3F7/05A3F7"> <span>Focus on Results</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```